# Oracle - Fetch row basd on highest column value

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following data:

```
ITEM         LOC    NAME                PROMO_ID
100281362   12004   MOB-ACC-FEB7-DEC31  56008
100281362   12004   SPO_CLR-MAY25-JUN4  58414
100281362   12004   MOB-ACC-FEB7-DEC31  56023
```

I want the result to be:

based on the highest PROMO_ID value
For every item/loc/name combination, it should only fetch one row with the highest promo_id

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
select ITEM, LOC, NAME, max(PROMO_ID) as PROMO_ID
from your_table
group by ITEM, LOC, NAME
```